Unknown SMD Component LP 27 L#
I'm trying to identify and find analog for the smd component on a PCB. The PCB is a an engine control unit from Mersedes W168. The unknown component is a 2-pin polar component in the red circle. The approximate size is 4.3*3.1 mm2. The label on the cover is "LP 27 L#" (where # is a symbol I cant recognize ). I am not 100% sure if the  first letter is actually "L" since the cover is damaged. I did the search of the label but didnt find the exact match. So far I suspect that this is some diode for 27 V.  Does anyone have any better ideas?



May be useful context: the neighboring/connected part is a https://mm.digikey.com/Volume0/opasdata/d220001/medias/docus/1079/VND10BSP_.pdf

hm thanks for the tip! I will check this line

@TimWilliams got an idea basing on your comment - the base of VND10BSP is actually Vcc for 26 V. The SMD may be a voltage stabilizer for 27 V for instance. I just need to check if the other side of the smd is actually the GND. Does it make sence?

The device limit is 40V, so it seems likely the diode is a TVS limiting supply to somewhat less than that. 27V would be fine for the device, though I don't know if that makes sense with the rest of the circuit. I don't recognize the diode offhand I'm afraid, but the purpose, and voltage rating, seem plausible. Also, those poor tantalums, placed on a low impedance supply :(

@TimWilliams Thank you for the help! I agree that some TVS seem to be the most likely candidate. I think I will go ahead with this.

should be a P6SMB27A diode in SMB package from FAGOR

No picture found but the following diagram shows the typical marking:

The logo of FAGOR is visible when zooming in your picture (not a # but a F).

Thank you a lot for the exact match! Indeed I didnt recognize the symbol at all and just put #

Hah nice coincidence, 27th week on a 27V diode.

@TimWilliams Yep indeed a surprising coincidence. Just imagined the component could have been from December batch:)
